# Софт для бэкапов Windows server 2012r2

Tags: резервное-копирование, windows-server

Подскажите пожалуйста софт для бэкапирования win server 2k12 r2.
Необходимо иметь возможность делать полный бэкап на уровне ФС, чтобы была возможность востановиться из этого бэкапа.
Заранее благодарю!

Comment: встроенный бэкап не устроит?

Answer (score 0):

Acronis Backup 11.5. Отличный вариант для бэкапа на уровне ФС. Есть возможность создания плана резервного копирования и плана восстановления данных. Можно восстанавливать диски в целом, тома или же отдельные файлы и папки.

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста более развёрнутый ответ.